# Best way to sync Outlook 2010 with Google Calendar on multiple computers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

I have Outlook 2010 installed on my laptop and desktop. Now I want to sync them, but Google Calendar Sync only supports Outlook 2003/2007 version. How can I do it now?

Comment: The best way by far is to use Exchange.  Outlook without Exchange is severely crippled and it's awful with IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can read here on how to sync Outlook 2010 with Google Calandar.

The page [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=69325d10cf1426f1&hl=en)

And the D/L links [here](http://mychannellogos.com/Documents/GoogleCalendarSync.zip)

Or also: http://oggsync.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KiGoo](http://download.cnet.com/KiGoo/3000-2155_4-201490.html) for syncing Calendar and Contacts.

> KiGoo is an application running over Kayxo Insight technology which uses low access MAPI protocol to natively manage all GCal appointments inside Microsoft Outlook. Kayxo Insight technology enables this capability acting as a bridge between any external API or database and Microsoft Outlook.
>
> Key Benefits:
>
> - Manage Exchange and Google Calendars in only one program.
> - Check free/busy availability of all Google Contacts who shared their information.
> - See, Browse, Update, Email and invite your Google Contacts from Microsoft Outlook .
> - No synchronization needed.
> - Real Time access.
> - Easy installation.
>
> Supports Microsoft Outlook 2007.  **It does not currently support Outlook 2010**
>
> KiGoo is free for non commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I use [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/) which has Outlook 2007, 2010 32bit as well as 2010 x64 support.

It has tons of options and is well worth the $19.99 IMO

Answer (score 0):

[Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98565) is now compatible with OL2010. (I'm unsure when it was updated to do so, but came across it last week and had to set it up on a Users computer with OL2010 - it worked flawlessly).

```
Compatibility
------------- 
Currently, Google Calendar Sync is only compatible with Microsoft 
Outlook versions 2003, 2007, 2010 and operating systems Windows XP, 
Windows Vista, and Windows 7. 

Windows XP 64-bit Edition is not compatible with Google Calendar Sync at this time.
```